# Naming convention for boolean variable with a trailing P

Tags: variables, naming, conventions

In the 90s, by CS professor said that there was a naming convention for boolean variables where you add a trailing capital P, because the P looks a bit like a question mark. Example: validP (valid?).  So if you see a variable with a P at the end, you know it's a boolean.

For some reason this anecdote stuck with me for 20+ years, however I cannot recall a single time that I have seen a variable named with a P at the end.  Maybe this was only a convention for a particular language that I have not used, or maybe it was a 90s thing.  I would really like to know. Has anyone else heard of this convention, and if so, in what context.

Comment: A "P" doesn't look like a question mark to me.

Comment: Remove the little line to the left of the curvy part of the P.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but lisp had a similar convention for naming predicate functions https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node69.html#:~:text=Common%20Lisp%20uses%20a%20uniform,hyphen%20in%20the%20existing%20name.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading about this naming convention in a science fiction short story, but I have never seen it used in real life. I just googled this exact question to see if anyone else had seen it used.

Answer (score 0):

I can remember learning to use this for names in Python. The 'p' stood for predicate and was intended to reinforce that it was a boolean value for the thing being named in the root part.